# Complex SQL with multiple inner join & count with rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I would like to know if it's possible to write very complex SQL with Rails Active Record helper like this one (numbers will be replaced by variables later) :

```
SELECT 
photographs.id,
(COUNT(distinct comments.id) / 50.0 * 100 * 0.25) + (15 * 0.1) + (COUNT(distinct likes.id) / 100.0 * 100 * 0.05) +(COUNT(distinct likes.id) / COUNT(distinct views.id) * 100 * 0.4) +(COUNT(distinct likes.id) * 2.4  / 100.0  * 0.2) AS FINAL_RANKING
FROM photographs
INNER JOIN comments 
ON photographs.id = comments.photograph_id
INNER JOIN likes 
ON photographs.id = likes.photograph_id
INNER JOIN views 
ON photographs.id = views.photograph_id
GROUP BY photographs.id
ORDER by FINAL_RANKING DESC;
```

I found on Rails doc more simple example or simple multiple inner join but without counts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails accepts SQL in the `select` command.

See [Active Record Query Interface | Selecting Specific Fields](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#selecting-specific-fields)

Something like this should work for you:

```
Photographs.joins(:comments, :likes, :views, :users).where(
"users.id = 1").select("COUNT(whatever)")
```

No guarantee that actually runs.

Comment: You could offer a guarantee.  You could guarantee that it works or his money back!

Comment: Wow... I am so surprised. I thought that was going to need retooling. Did you change it much?

Comment: I write a new question it's a different problem :)